# Vanilla Javascript code to sort nested tables

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, dom

I have written a code to sort a main table containing tables in each of its rows. Here I am trying to sort the table by first sorting the rows in each of the main rows and then sorting the table from the sorted main rows. Whenever I click on headers the table is sorted in ascending and descending order alternately. How can I make this code more efficient and elegant in a JS way?

```js
let headers = document.querySelectorAll('.percentage_header');
headers.forEach(header => header.addEventListener('click', sortAll));

var sortDir = 1;

var mainTable = document.querySelector('.main_results_table');
var mainTableRows =  Array.from(mainTable.querySelectorAll('.main_table_rows'));

var individualRowsFromMainTableRows = document.querySelectorAll('.individual_rows');

function sortAll() {
  individualRowsFromMainTableRows.forEach(function(row) { 
    individualStudentResults = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll(".single_test_row"));
    individualStudentResults.sort(function(a,b){
      if(a.querySelector(".percentage_value") == undefined) return 1;
    if(b.querySelector(".percentage_value") == undefined) return 0;
    return sortDir == -1 ? (a.querySelector(".percentage_value").textContent > b.querySelector(".percentage_value").textContent) : (a.querySelector(".percentage_value").textContent < b.querySelector(".percentage_value").textContent);
    // return parseFloat(a.querySelector(".theory_percentage_value").textContent) - parseFloat(b.querySelector(".theory_percentage_value").textContent) * sortDir;
    })
    individualStudentResults.forEach(individualStudentResult => row.appendChild(individualStudentResult));
  })  

  mainTableRows.sort((a, b) => sortDir * (getVal(a) - getVal(b)));            
  mainTableRows.forEach(mainTableRow => mainTable.appendChild(mainTableRow));
  sortDir = -sortDir
}

function getVal(rw) {
    var a = parseFloat(rw.querySelector('.individual_rows .single_test_row .percentage_value').textContent);
    return a ? a : 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="main_results_table">
  
    <tr class="main_table_rows">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="individual_rows">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th class="percentage_header">Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="single_test_row">
            <td class="values">
              <td class="percentage_value">48%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="single_test_row">
            <td class="values">
              <td class="percentage_value">N/A</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="single_test_row">
            <td class="values">
              <td class="percentage_value">22%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="main_table_rows">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="individual_rows">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th class="percentage_header">Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="single_test_row">
            <td class="values">
              <td class="percentage_value">58%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="single_test_row">
            <td class="values">
              <td class="percentage_value">68%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="single_test_row">
            <td class="values">
              <td class="percentage_value">78%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="main_table_rows">
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>email</li>
          <li>address</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="individual_rows">
          <tr class="row_header">
            <th>person_status</th>
            <th class="percentage_header">Total theory percentage</th>
            <th>Total practicals percentage</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="single_test_row">
            <td class="values">
              <td class="percentage_value">99%</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="single_test_row">
            <td class="values">
              <td class="percentage_value">N/A</td>
              <td>88%</td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: You're sorting the rows with the class `main_table_rows` instead of the rows inside the `individual_rows` tables

Comment: Am I not sorting the rows inside the `individual_rows` first and then sorting the `main_table_rows` as per the `sorted` `individual_rows` inside each of the `main_table_rows`? As soon as the `sortAll` function is called I thought I am doing the same. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. Your sort function for individual rows returns either `0`, `1`, `true` or `false` though, where it should return either `-1`, `0` or `1`

Comment: I do not know if it is a silly question but what does returning `-1`, `0` or `1` do differently from the present values? I do not know the difference.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description